# Prove p, assuming the following: (1) r → ¬q (2) q (3) ¬(p ∧ ¬s) ∧ (¬r → p)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Prove p, assuming the following:

- (1) r → ¬q                         assumption
- (2) q                              assumption
- (3) ¬(p ∧ ¬s) ∧ (¬r → p)           assumption
- I need help after (4) not sure how to start this
- (4) q → ¬r                        contrapostion (1)
- (5)¬r                             modus ponens (2),(4)
- (6)
- (7)

Comment: (4) is wrong....

Comment: Use Contraposition on (1) to get $q \to \lnot r$. Then use MP with (2) to get $\lnot r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prove p, assuming the following:

(1) r → ¬q assumption
(2) q assumption
(3) ¬(p ∧ ¬s) ∧ (¬r → p) assumption
I need help after (4) not sure how to start this
(4) q → ¬r contrapostion (1)
(5)¬r modus ponens (2),(4)
(6) p Modus ponens (3),(4)
I figured it out!